# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Error when passing xml body

Tags: xml, rest, powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that calls a rest web service.  The code below is the most basic call I have to make to query the api and return information for a specific device.  Running this same script I get inconsistent results where sometimes it works fine and sometimes it returns this error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.
>   At E:\temp\temp.ps1:28 char:18
>   + $searchResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $searchURI -Credential $cr ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ProtocolViolationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.ProtocolViolationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodComm
>      and

I cannot figure out what that error means or why it works intermittently.  When the Powershell script fails with that error I have run tests against the target web service from Postman and confirmed that the web service is up and functioning normally.

```
#Get PS Credential Object
$user = "user"
$pass = "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)

$searchURI = "http://internal.server.com:8080/spectrum/restful/models"

$searchBody = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rs:model-request xmlns:rs="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/request" throttlesize="250000">
<rs:target-models><rs:models-search><rs:search-criteria xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/filter">
<devices-only-search />
<filtered-models>
<has-substring-ignore-case>
<attribute id="0x1006e">
<value>SERVER1234</value>
</attribute>
</has-substring-ignore-case>
</filtered-models>
</rs:search-criteria>
</rs:models-search>
</rs:target-models>
</rs:model-request>
"@

$searchResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $searchURI -Credential $cred -Body $searchBody -ContentType "application/xml"
write-host $searchResults.OuterXml
```

Comment: Try adding Content-Length to your headers and see if it makes a difference.

`$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"` and `$headers.Add("Content-Length", '518')`. Finally call `Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $searchURI -Credential $cred -Body $searchBody -ContentType "application/xml" -Headers $headers` with the added header. Just modify the actual header to contain the actual length of your request. Length of you request body you can get by running `$searchBody.Length`.

Comment: YOu have a trailing bracket on that line. That should trigger a syntax error. Is that a fragment from posting or is that your actual code?

Comment: @Kim, I tried adding the Content-Length as suggested but got a new error about the header "Invoke-RestMethod : This header must be modified using the appropriate property or method. Parameter name: name".

Comment: @Matt, the trailing bracket is not in the actual code, must have been an copy paste error.  I have removed it from the example code above.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278977/powershell-v3-invoke-restmethod-headers. It might be related and the header is not modifiable when using `Invoke-RestMethod`. Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921529/powershell-webrequest-post for how to do web requests using other methods.